# Targeting an element by its content

Tags: javascript, html

How I can get DOM-element if I had and `@media() ...` in the content of this element? This is something like custom template engine that I made.

For case below, I need an `<article>` Node and `<time>` Node, because upper on every of these nodes exists @media tag (one or more).

```html
    <div class="d-flex mt-20 vertical-around-flex">
        @media(1080) mmw-400 mmh-300
        @media(770) mmw-300
        <article class="card bubble mmw-500 mmh-400">
            @media(770) hide
            <time>14 June, 2023</time>
        </article>
    </div>
```

`@media(1080) mmw-400 mmh-300` connected to `<article>` 
`@media(770) mmw-300` connected to `<article>` 
`@media(770) hide` connected to `<time>`

I need `@media` text and connected **NODE element**. Example structure:

```js
{
    ARTICLE_NODE: {
        "media": "1080": {
            "classes": ["mmw-400", "mmh-300"]
        }
        "media": "770": {
            "classes": ["mmw-300"]
        }
    },
    TIME_NODE: {
        "media": "770": {
            "classes": ["hide"]
        }    
    }

}
```

This is my code but it not working properly. This code return 6 Nodes, but I need 2 instead. Also, this code does not return me the `@media` text, only a HTML DomElement

```js
        const REGEX_MEDIA = new RegExp('@media\\((\\d+)\\)\\s(.+)\\n', 'gm');
        const HTML = document.body.innerHTML;
        
        console.log(
            Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('*')).filter(function(element) {
                const match = element.outerHTML.match(REGEX_MEDIA);

                if (match == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (match === void 0) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            })
        )
```

Comment: If you're just looking for the content within the `article` elements, change `querySelectorAll('*')` to `querySelectorAll('article')`. It would also make more sense to use `innerHTML` instead of `outerHTML` given your requirements.

Comment: How come `"media": "770":` should have 2 values? `["mmw-400", "mmh-300"]`

Comment: @Thefourthbird my fault, you're right. Replaced, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No regexps needed. Just walk the node tree, look for text nodes that contain your `@media` tag and grab that value and the next sibling element (which is the "tagged" element).

Formatting the `nodes` from the example below to your object structure is left as a separate exercise.

```js
const nodes = [];

function walkChildNodes(n) {
  for (let c of n.childNodes) {
    if (c.nodeType === 3) { // text node
      const val = c.nodeValue.trim();
      if (val.startsWith("@media")) {
        nodes.push([val, c.nextSibling]);
      }
    } else {
      if (c.hasChildNodes()) {
        walkChildNodes(c);
      }
    }
  }

}
walkChildNodes(document.body);
console.log(nodes);
```

```html
<div class="d-flex mt-20 vertical-around-flex">
  @media(1080) mmw-400 mmh-300 @media(770) mmw-300
  <article class="card bubble mmw-500 mmh-400">
    @media(770) hide
    <time>14 June, 2023</time>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much! I'm set your answer done after 6 mins (stackoverflow timing). Thanks!!!